# React state hook not passing changes to element

Tags: reactjs

I've the following (simplified) code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

const CheckIn = props => {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    //send request to checkin :)
    setSuccess(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button color="default" variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>Check-in</Button>
      <Alert open={success} severity="success">Succes</Alert>
      <Alert open={error} severity="error">Error</Alert>
    </>
  )
}

const Alert = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(props.open);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
      <MuiAlert severity={props.severity} onClose={handleClose}>
        {props.children}
      </MuiAlert>
    </Snackbar>
  )
}
```

My expectation is that when the button is pressed from the CheckIn component the `success` variable is set to `true` and passed on to the Alert component, which will open the `Snackbar` and show the alert on screen. Following that after 6 seconds the `Snackbar` fires the `handleClose` and closes the alert again.

What happens now is that the alert never pops-up. What I've tried is changing `Snackbar open={open}` to `Snackbar open={props.open}` to check if the property is passed correctly from the parent, which works but the alert can't be closed anymore after that.

I'm mostly searching as to why it's not working opposed to having a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently setOpen in Alert only sets local state in Alert but open in CheckIn did not change. Instead of copying the prop you can pass a function from CheckIn to Alert to change the open value in CheckIn.

Since the Alert (and it's close button) only shows when open is true you can close the alert with toggle.

```js
const CheckIn = () => {
  const [success, setSuccess] = React.useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(true);

  const toggleSuccess = React.useCallback(
    () => setSuccess(success => !success),
    []
  );
  const toggleError = React.useCallback(
    () => setError(error => !error),
    []
  );

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={toggleSuccess}>
        toggle success
      </button>
      <button onClick={toggleError}>toggle error</button>
      <div>
        <Alert open={success} close={toggleSuccess}>
          Succes
        </Alert>
        <Alert open={error} close={toggleError}>
          Error
        </Alert>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Alert = ({ open, close, children }) => {
  return open ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      {children}
      <div>
        <button onClick={close}>close</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    ''
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <CheckIn />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I understand you can pass a function from its parent to handle the state of the child. But in my case the parent component shouldn't care about any of the logic that happens inside the child component apart from setting its initial state. So why should the child update it's state through the parent?

Comment: `But in my case the parent component shouldn't care about any of the logic that happens inside the child component apart from setting its initial state` Then why does the parent have `success` state and a button to change it? Your parent (CheckIn) **already** has the state and the logic to change the Alert.

Comment: :) yep sorry disregard that. Wasn't thinking properly. So the reason my code does not work is due to `useState` only setting the initial state and not reacting to any changes that are later done to `props.open`?

Comment: @404 Exactly, Alert only uses props.open when it mounts to copy to local state, after that you can't control Alert from CheckIn anymore unless you unmount it or (maybe) provide a unique key to it. I would not advice doing this and let Alert be controlled by it's parent because that is what you probably want.